# How to update created and modified properties to my own value of a file in SharePoint online using REST API in C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api

Isn't it possible to update `created` and `modified` like the following method?

This works for other column properties but nothing happens in `modified` and `created` column.

```
var body = "{ '__metadata': {'type':'SP.ListItem'},'Modified':'2012-03-30T17:24:17Z'}";

var json = client.UploadString(url, body);
```

Comment: SInce it is a read-only field, so updating with Rest Api will need 3 calls. Better or use CSOM or JSOM library for this task. This link contains more explanation to it.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146116/update-readonly-field-using-rest-api

Comment: Is there any sample codes done using REST API.

Comment: Sorry couldn't find any good resource

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, It's not possible. But There is workaround for that. Basically, `Created` and `Modified` columns are **ReadOnly** columns.

So, We need to modify list schema to make these available for modification (set **ReadOnly** attribute to **false**) as shown below for `Created` field.

```
var updateCreatedDate = "<Fields>" + 
"<Method ID='1'><Field ID='{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}' ColName='tp_Created' RowOrdinal='0' ReadOnly='FALSE' Type='DateTime' Name='Created' DisplayName='Created' StorageTZ='TRUE' SourceID='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3' StaticName='Created' FromBaseType='TRUE' Version='4' ShowInNewForm='FALSE' ShowInEditForm='FALSE' /></Method>" +
"</Fields>";
        $().SPServices({
          operation: "UpdateList",
          listName: "Events",
          listProperties:"",
          updateFields: updateCreatedDate,
          newFields: "",
          deleteFields: "",
          listVersion: "",
          async: false,
          completefunc: function (xData, Status){ 
              alert('Created Date is now available for modification'); 
          }
        });
```

`Created` field value can be updated using `UpdateListItems` operation:

```
var updatedDate = new Date('2018-01-01 6:00:00').toISOString();
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Events",
    ID: 1,
    valuepairs: [["Created", updatedDate]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         alert('Created Date is successfully updated');
    }
});
```